# jQuery doesn't show .attr('checked')

Tags: jquery

Why does jQuery don't return value of 'checked' attribute?

It always returns 'checked', no matter what is in it.

```
<div id='div' checked='checked_value'></div>
<script>
    var attr_value = $('#div').attr('checked');
    alert(attr_value);
    // attr_value == 'checked' no matter what
</script>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/BbRmH/2/

It was okay, in 1.4, but when I upgraded to 1.8 it totally messed my code. I use `checked` attribute a lot.

Comment: It would be better to use data attributes to avoid such quirks.

Comment: @Musa, well, yes. But it really has "checked" meaning.

Comment: I didn't notice that element is a div element, `check` is a not a valid attribute for a div element. Try using `data` attributes instead http://jsfiddle.net/cHpgb/

Comment: jQuery recognizes `checked` as a boolean attribute, so it doesn't care what its value is and just returns `checked`, if you want the value use native dom methods, see http://jsfiddle.net/BbRmH/5/

Comment: So, please post answer, that there is no way to make it work, for closing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe in the more recent versions of jQuery the correct syntax would be -

```
$("element").prop('checked');
```

> The difference between attributes and properties can be important in specific situations. Before jQuery 1.6, the [`.attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) method sometimes took property values into account when retrieving some attributes, which could cause inconsistent behavior. As of jQuery 1.6, the .prop() method provides a way to explicitly retrieve property values, while .attr() retrieves attributes.

- [`prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/)

---

I believe however, that you might be using this property incorrectly. Usually, one would just test for the existence of the `checked` selector. There can really only be two states. Checked and unchecked. Usually, one would use something like this -

```
$('.groupOfCheckboxes:checked')
```

This would return a list of all the matched checkboxes that are checked. You also used this property on a `<div>` element. This is not valid HTML. You should really stick to valid markup if you want the most consistent results across browsers.

Comment: @mar - `HMTL`... It's a new variation I invented. HYPER MAKEUP TEXT LANGUAGE. It's gonna be huge...